# How to merge two data to one in a given column in python

Tags: python, merge, drop

How're you today?
I am having difficulty in treating the gender column, considering it has a data entry error `"Fe male"`.

Can it be dropped? If yes, how can I go about it?
Can it be merged? If yes, how can I treat this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Zeezou, can you mark my solution below as answer if it was helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

To replace the fields "Fe Male" with "Female", you can simply use the `replace()`method.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ "Gender":["Female", "Male", "Fe Male", "Female", "Fe Male"]})
df1 = df1.replace("Fe Male", "Female")
df1
```

Outcome: 
[image: outcome of the code]